# How to find a duplicate element in an unordered array using constant space

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search, duplicates

I am revising exam questions and I have come accross this one that I cannot solve (10.a).

Since I can't modify the array I know I cannot use Bubble Sort for instance, but the bit that is throwing me is the **"not dependent on n"**, the only idea I can come up with would be to select the `array[i]` element and compare it to `array[i+j]` which I understand is not allowed since it would dependent on `n`.

We are several in our course scratching out heads at how should we approach this one, anybody could give us an idea on how to solve it?

For the second part we are OK since we have done a few search algorithm that could solve the question.

[image]

Comment: "array[i] element and compare it to array[i+n]" - if you mean array[i+j], then yes, that is the answer, and it is allowed because the space is not dependent on n\*. Why do you think it would be dependent on n?

Comment: There is no additional space involved in comparing elements of the input array.

Comment: For 10a you are supposed to use the obvious O(n^2) algorithm, i.e., test each pair.  For 10b you are supposed to sort first and then look for adjacent duplicates, or use a hash table or other indexing structure.

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant array[i+j], then I am getting cofused as to what "constant amount of additional space, not dependent on n' means, as I thought he meant we weren't allowed to basically do a Linear Search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> may use only a constant amount of additional space

This means that your algorithm is only allowed to use a fixed number of memory cells. However, it does not mean that you're forbidden to access memory holding the input array.

Note that the question is talking about constant *space*, not constant *time*.

A solution that compares every `array[i]` to `array[i+j]` is perfectly acceptable, since it only needs 1 additional memory cell (holding the result).

Comment: So basically no recursion or stack calls?

Comment: @Sergi: Recursion may still be fine if its stack consumption does not depend on the arrray size n. That is the case for tail-recursion (which can effectively be rewritten to a loop).